# Ignore non-words and apply a string method to words

Tags: python, string

Having a variable with a large message, how to ignore exclamation marks and symbols while applying a string method to the words that are part of this message?
Example:

```
message = "THIS IS A MESSAGE!!, A TEXT *THAT HAS MANY-- WORDS- "
```

The above should become:

```
"this is a message a text that has many words"
```

I did it as shown below:

```
ignore_stuff = message.replace('*',"").replace('--',"").replace(",","").replace("!","")
turned_to_lower = ignore_stuff.lower()
print(turned_to_lower)
```

which gives the wanted result:

```
this is a message a text that has many words
```

Is there a better way that still does not use any external libraries and also does not use regular expressions?

Comment: This is more of an opinionated question, which would better be asked in something like [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why are you only replacing certain characters and substrings? Why not strip everything that is not [a-zA-Z] or space (and optionally [0-9] if that's valid)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.isalnum()` and `.isspace()`

```
message = "This is a sentence --- and this is great."
message = "".join(ch.lower() for ch in message if ch.isalnum() or ch.isspace())
message = " ".join(message.split())
print(message)
```

Comment: How would you address cases where some of the removed symbols have caused very wide spaces between words? For example, if in the message there is this sentence: `This is a sentence --- and this is great.` The removal of the dashes will leave a big space. How can this be solved?

Comment: Might require two steps. Do `' '.join(message.split())` after what I have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: can you update your answer to take care of this case as well all in one?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to S P Sharan's answer, but doing it with only one `join`:

```
message = "THIS IS A MESSAGE!!, A TEXT *THAT HAS MANY   -- WORDS- "
clean = "".join(
    last:=l.lower() for l in message.strip()
    if l.isalnum() or (l.isspace() and not last.isspace())
)
print(clean)
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is make a list of letters and remove anything in the string that is not in the list.
Like this:

```
letters = [' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
message = "THIS IS A MESSAGE!!, A TEXT *THAT HAS MANY-- WORDS- "
changed_message = ""
for l in message:
    if l.lower() in letters:
        changed_message += l.lower()
```